# linear regression matlab

Tags: regression, linear

I have three predictor variables

A: binary  (A = vector of length N containing 0 and 1)

B: three categories 1, 2, 3 (B = vector of length N containing 1,2 or 3)

C: continuous (C = vector of length N containing real, positive integers)

and one response variable

y: binary (y = vector of length N, where half entries are 0 and other half are 1).

Bcat = dummyvar(B);

Bcat = Bcat(:,2:3); % remove the first column

X = [A Bcat C];

b           = glmfit(X,y,'binomial','link','logit');

So for a particular n (n=1..N) then the probability of y(n) being 1 is given by

eta         = b(1) + X(n,1)*b(2) + X(n,2)*b(3) + X(n,3)*b(4) + X(n,4)*b(5);

Prob(n)   = exp(eta)/(1+exp(eta));

But this gives a range around 0.5 for all values, where I would like it to be 1 where the initial input y vector stated it is 1 for certain.

Comment: It's a little unclear what your question is.  Are you asking why the predicted probabilities are not exactly the same as the values in $y$?

Comment: Firstly, thank you for your help. 

Yes. I'm trying to predict the probability of a success in N different events. 

I already have a success for half the events, given in y. 
I'm trying to make predictions for the other half. 

I would expect entries in Prob to be 1 where the y vector is 1. 
For example, if y(n) = 1, then wouldn't Prob(n) = 1 since we already know a success occurred here? 

Thanks again!

Comment: You are asking for something mathematically impossible, because $\exp(\eta)/(1+\exp(\eta))$ can never equal $1$ or $0$.

Answer (score 0):

The linear regression does not give you the value of $0$ or $1$ but the probability of being $1$.

If you want the expected response variable to be binary, you need some kind of cutoff like :

$\frac{e^{\eta}}{(1+e^{\eta})}>0.5 = 1 $,

$\frac{e^{\eta}}{(1+e^{\eta})}<0.5 = 0 $.

Comment: Thanks. However, sometimes I get the same probability, say 0.57 for n=1 and n=2. Yet the initial y vector that I provide states success for n=1 (that is, y(1) = 1), but not n=2 (y(2) = 0).

I would assume that values where y(n) = 1, would have a probability 1 of success.

Comment: @user101051 I get why you would think that. But you are never gonna predict perfectly not even in the estimated sample